# How can I increase my Vault Dweller's Happiness?

Tags: fallout-shelter

All my vault dwellers look really unhappy and bummed out and aside from making babies I'm not sure how to make them happier.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: You should fit all their needs (water, food, electricity and maybe medicine). Most of them should have a good job. This will do the trick. Maybe you should increase their living room. Do you have some issues that your happiness is quite low?

Comment: I do. i think I expanded too quickly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think there are four reasons why dwellers get unhappy:

1. **Injury**: If they are injured, heal them with stimpacks
2. **Hungry/Thirsty**: Make sure you have enough water and food (the indicators should not be red)
3. **Job**: Make sure they are assigned to the correct job. Check the SPECIAL attributes and place every Dweller in a job where he/she has the most points at.
4. **Irradiated**: If they are irradiated (they have a red bar on their health meter), remove radiation with RadAway.

If you zoom in on a particular Dweller, they will talk, and say why they are unhappy.

One of the tips in the loading screens said a Radio Station makes Dwellers happy. Not sure this increases the general happiness or only counts for those Dwellers assigned to the Radio Station. There might be other structures which will increase happiness. I have seen there is a garden (but I can't build it yet to confirm).

Comment: Rushing a room also seems to affect happiness. Happiness will drop with a fail and increase with a success.

Comment: Additionally dwellers that recent had sex get a big happiness boost (I think it always goes to 100%) for some time.

Comment: I haven't scienced it, but it appears that assigning a person to the Radio Station gives a +1% bump to all dwellers.  Similarly, taking a person out of the Radio Station gives -1%.

Comment: Also, a successful rush gives everyone in that room +10%.  A failed rush decreases the happiness, but I haven't yet figured out the exact amount.

Comment: It also appears being in a room with a corpse decreases their happiness.

Comment: Oh, for female dwellers, pregnant = happy. Not sure if offensive or funny. Offensively funny, maybe?

Answer (score 8):

Another point about happiness is that the dancing action (not something you directly control) in the Living Quarters also increases happiness. If you want a dweller to get happier, put him/her in a living quarters with a dweller of the opposite sex, and wait until they start dancing. If you don't want a baby, you can just reallocate one/both of them to another room before the magic happens. That should increase their happiness dramatically.

I've yet to see radio stations (even for a dweller with high Charisma) get happy from using the station, but perhaps I haven't waited long enough.

Comment: Sometimes dwellers will want to listen to the radio.  They'll even say it if you watch them.  I think that's what increases their happiness.