# What's the best room to assign dwellers to?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a quest that requires me to assign 15 dwellers to the right room for them, and I seem to be stuck at 9. I don't have access to all possible rooms yet, so that may be a part of my problem, but in general...

Is there a way to tell which room a dweller will like best short of assigning them to random rooms to see which sticks?

I tried going by the highest SPECIAL score, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223815/how-can-i-increase-my-vault-dwellers-happiness). The first answer 3rd point is what you're looking for.

Comment: This quest is the reason they included the option to skip 1 quest per day

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck on this quest too. What solved it for me was assigning *new* dwellers to the job that uses their highest SPECIAL stat. I had existing dwellers already working in their optimal room, but these were not counted and didn't increase the X out of 15 even if I assigned them to a different room and back to the optimal room or if I moved them to a different optimal room of the same stat (like a different power plant for a strong dweller).

Dwellers that grew up from children and new arrivals from the wasteland did increment the X out of 15 when I assigned them to the room using their highest SPECIAL stat.

Comment: Ugh, I keep tripping over the "from now, do this thing to dwellers or rooms that you've never done the thing to before" nature of the quests in this game. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear yep, the send dwellers to the wasteland for x hours" doesn't include people that left the vault before the quest started, same goes for "have x pregnant dwellers" if they were already pregnant. I'm not sure how I'll finish these quests once I hit population cap.

Answer (score 5):

This has been driving me NUTS. So I did a ton of testing and boy am I glad I did, because I got a "assign 30 dweller's" objective. These are tested from a kind of "how I think it is coded" sort of way if that makes sense. So here is what I have found:

1. When the objective is given to you, all dwellers can be assigned to a room only ONCE. That means if you assign them and get the objective credit, they are done.
2. Even if a person is already in a room they like, it is possible to get their "point" towards the objective, if you swap their clothing which would make a different stat higher, changing the room they would find as the "best fit"
3. Training rooms of the SPECIAL type count as that type of best fit room
4. Residence rooms do not seem to count for charisma.
5. People exploring and on "coffee break" can simply be assigned to the room of choice easy peasy. That makes having a high number of coffee break and exploring people desirable as this quest seems to provide lunch boxes. 30 is my personal highest on the objective with a population of 135. I'm sure it goes higher, I'm not even a quarter way to the bottom of the world in rooms yet...
6. If you have a person with say, 8 strength in the power room, and can't get clothing to surpass his strength changing his room, you must train his other skills higher, this will allow his room to change, and therefore allow him to get the objective point for you.

It is possible I am missing some things. I have one more theory I would like to test but have not been able to and can't until I get the objective again. So, if any of you get it, please test this and I would appreciate it :D

The test:

- When you get the objective, a dweller already in their best fit room may have the ability to change rooms with different outfit. To help me understand the "logic" in game. Move them to the wrong room, change their clothing to that room which would then make that room their "best fit" room, and see if you get the point. If YOU DON'T, then put their old outfit on and move them back. If you still don't, then I would want you to put on the other outfit again, changing their room, and move them to that room. That should get them the point if my findings are indeed accurate.

Thanks a lot folks!

Edit...

Bad news. I got the achievement again. This time I tried my theory out, no matter what. Some people who were already in their best room just would not count if I changed their stats. Some changes however seemed random. There is a possibility that their base normal stats come into play over their altered stats by gear. Frankly I'm tired of trying to figure this one out. If anyone makes some concrete ground breaking finding please share. Sorry for any misleading info I'll leave my previous list incase it helps anyone.

Happy overseeing.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell which room is right for them when the corners light up green for that room when you're about to place them. To replace them into the same room if you get the objective again, just make them explore the wastes for a bit then recall them, but don't assign them to a room immediately, just let them wander the vault a moment.

My main problem is that I have a dweller that doesn't have a "right" room.

Comment: Build one of those training rooms and have them train up a SPECIAL stat. Then they'll have a "right" room.

Answer (score 2):

I always just drag the dwellers to a room and drag them right back. You will get the achievement by just trying out every room and dragging dwellers back to the room where they already were. It is a lot of work but it works

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is look at their skills and see which is the highest and you will also benefit by putting them in the right room because they will work better and faster, and also be happier they get to use the right skill they have the highest. I hope this helps!