# Is there a faster way of completing an objective asking for a dweller with a specific attribute?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout: Shelter, you sometimes get objectives with conditions that are already satisfied, such as:

> Assign *X* dwellers to the right room

This objective is detailed in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225928/whats-the-best-room-to-assign-dwellers-to), and appears to be a hopeless case. I recently got the above one (which I removed, since I wasn't ready for a growth of *X+* people), but immediately after I got rid of it, I got the following:

> Have 1 Bald Dweller in the Vault

I already have two bald dwellers, but the objective doesn't trigger. I've tried sending one of them out to the wasteland and recalling, without success.

Waiting for a random bald dweller to show up could take a **very** long time, and isn't reliable. Another way would be to breed one, but I'm not sure if I can affect the hair of coming babies in any way (do boys inherit baldness from their father?).

Is there any clever way to complete this objective in reasonable time (through some trickery and/or breeding)?

Comment: The first one can be completed with dwellers you have that might have good stats for another room and be moved to them. For example, you got a high perception and agility dweller in a water room, move it to a fast food or garden and it should work. I think the dweller needs 3 or 4+ of the stats for it to trigger.

Comment: Build a Barber Shop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, Fallout Shelter objectives can sometimes be weird or frustrating but depending on the reward you can decide it's worth the trouble or dismiss it (if you haven't dismissed anything else that day).

How I completed several `Assign X dwellers to the right room` objectives was to **send dwellers exploring the wasteland and when they come back you assign them to the right room** or **retrain a dweller on another skill**. If it has 3 S and 2 A, you retrain his Agility and put him in the Diner.

This can take a lot of time but like I said, it all depends on the objective's reward. The second objective: `Have 1 Bald Dweller in the Vault` can take even more time but you can start by making a lot of kids. You need the people for your Vault anyway... I'm making around 10 people a day. Today, 2 of them were bald. So it's just chance. If you have radios, there's also the chance that a new dweller is bald...

**Remember the fact that Fallout Shelter it's not really the type of game were you start and play for hours... there are objectives or actions that can take hours or days in real life so you just adapt to this gameplay.** It's a bit like a Tamagotchi :)

Comment: Good answer, even if the answer to the question in the title is "no". Accepting this until someone confirms a reliable method.

Answer (score 4):

**You MAY get baldness in offspring by breeding a bald guy, and as you suggested, which will speed up gaining the objective, if it is the case.**

Hair types do not appear to be "just random", and the same is likely to be true of other cosmetic attributes (and definitely seems true even of SPECIAL attributes).

I've several boys with the same hair as their dads. So baldness also should be, too. On checking, two males in my vault are bald and share the last same name; and no men who share the same name have one bald, one not, so it does seem mainly inheritable.

[EDIT: On further checking, this seems FALSE. I'm doing further tests, so the baldest guy in my vault is now at 100% happiness forever, permanently posted to the barracks and having a veritable harem of every non-related woman in the vault sent to him on a regular basis. So far, stats suggest "not heritable, my earlier results were a fluke." But, am testing further to be sure. The bald guy's not complaining.]

Comment: This seems more befitting of a comment than an answer, since it doesn't really provide a full answer to the question.

Comment: No, no, I meant, you haven't answered what the question mainly asks. The final sentence asks the question that needs to be answered: *Is there any clever way to complete this objective in reasonable time (through some trickery and/or breeding)?* You've only added what would be more befitting of a comment to Spauny's answer.

Comment: This might not be worded perfectly, but I think this is an acceptable answer. It directly addresses the question of how to quickly get a bald dweller.

Comment: It does seem to answer the question. I will try this method and accept it if it works.

Comment: No problem. In fact, now that I think about it, I have also royally screwed up, having made a bit of an embarrassment of myself here.

Comment: Hmm, I tried breeding my bald guy a few times. He had three sons, all of which had full heads of hair. So it would seem I was either really unlucky, or this isn't a reliable method at all. Either way, it certainly not 100%.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't expect it to be 100%, though I'd expect it to raise the odds to close to 50%, because while children don't look identical to either parent, they seem to have traits made from the traits of both parents, enough that they look visually similar to both. There may also be some randomness, too, taking it less than 50%, but should still be considerably better than just hoping for baldness from two hairy parents. If there was such a thing as a bald woman you'd be able to have either 100% chance, or at least 100% minus whatever fraction is random. But I've seen no bald women.

Comment: 5 sons, still none bald. However, another couple (with a non-bald guy) just got a bald kid. To me it seems completely random.

Comment: Interesting. Do your offspring appear entirely visually dissimilar to the parents, or just in their hair? And are you on iOS or Droid? I'm using Droid, and offspring in my vault seem like a mix of the features of the parents, with high reliability.

Comment: @DewiMorgan On Android. Still no balds from the baldy, but two balds from the non-bald one. Can't really see any major likeness, except (maybe) skin colour.

Comment: Hrm. I am no longer happy with my answer at all. I edited it to remove the sound of uncertainty, but did not replace that with actual certain data.

There is only one possible course of action. I must breed as many babies as possible, and keep rigorous notes! BREED, my pretties, BREED! We're gonna science the crap outta this thing!

Conveniently, I just got a "have 13 babies for a chest" goal...

Comment: Testing is not looking good for the heritable-baldness theory so far!

Comment: I like the modifications you made, showing that it is indeed not hereditary.

Answer (score 2):

If the mother is irradiated while pregnant, you'll get a beautiful bald baby. Thanks to this guy for figuring it out: https://zambrella.com/2015/08/20/review-fallout-shelter-creating-a-vault-of-my-time-and-a-wasteland-of-my-social-life/

Comment: I cannot even open that link, can someone test this? How would you reliably make her irradiated while pregnant?

Comment: Send her out, get max rads, return and make her pregnant before the rads get cured. Don't know if the above hypothesis is true thou.

Answer (score 2):

Baldness is inherited through the female. Try breeding the daughter of a bald man. Her son might be bald. 50% chance IRL

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug or cheat...

I've had task "Have 5 Bald Dwellers in the Vault", but I only had two of them. If you send one of them to explore wasteland, then recall immediately it counts him up again. In other words, game counts the same dweller each time he enters the vault.