# Raising a dweller's happiness

Tags: fallout-shelter

This is related to [How can I increase my Vault Dweller's Happiness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223815/how-can-i-increase-my-vault-dwellers-happiness), but slightly different.

I know what *can* raise a dweller's happiness, but what I want to know is what can raise it by how much?

For example, being a healthy, unaffected dweller with no job keeps a dweller's happiness at 50%. Then on the other hand, breeding raises it up to 100%. However I have noticed that there are fairly definitive "levels" throughout the vault. Generally at 100%, 90-80%, 75%, and 50%.

I know what can *lower* a dweller's happiness, and I know that breeding is a guaranteed boost to 100%, but I can't always afford to have a Vault full of pregnant women.

So, to clarify my question - **What Vault features raise a dweller's happiness; and to what level?**

Comment: Successfully rushing a room used to boost by 10%, but i last played so many versions ago that i don't know if its still accurate or not

Comment: @godemperordune: I can confirm that it is still accurate... Failing a rush does also still lower by 10%

Comment: ...and it can be applied more than once, so you can rush up the happines to 100% just by more successful rushes.

Comment: I think that working in the appropriate room or training room increases happiness to 75%. I think everything in between 100 and 75 is due to partial happiness loss, probably from disasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happiness can be positively affected by several things, primarily (but not restricted to):

- **Mating**. This will automatically raise a dweller's happiness to 100%.
- **Successfully rushing a room**. Raises happiness by 10%
- **Healing a dweller**. This will raise a dweller's happiness back to their original happiness. I.e. if a dweller's happiness was at 50%, they then took damage/radiation poisoning, which lowered their happiness, they will return to 50%<sup>[citation needed]</sup>
- **The Radio Room***. This automatically raises vault-wide happiness.
- **Bottle and Cappy***. The Nuka-Cola mascots occasionally visit your vault (if you have completed the "[Nabbed from Nuka-World](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_quests)" event) and raise vault-wide happiness for a short time.

Happiness can also be affected negatively in several ways as well, including:

- **Dying**. This can severely affect dweller happiness, often causing it to drop to minimal levels
- **Failing a rush**. Unsuccessfully rushing a room can cause dwellers to lose 10% happiness.
- **Getting sick/injured**. Taking large amounts of damage or radiation poisoning can cause dweller happiness to drop.
- **Not enough food/water**. If the vault supply stores drop below the minimum requirements, vault-wide happiness will be reduced. This may also be applicable to losing power.
- **Dead bodies**. If a dweller has died in a room, all other dwellers in that room will lose significant levels of happiness. (May affect vault-wide happiness).

*Sources needed for how much these affect happiness.

Answer (score 0):

Playing on PC.
I had one male dweller with happiness at 10%.
After breeding his happiness was 72% - and increase of 62%.
I didn't check his happiness immediately after breeding; I checked it after I sent him back to his assignment.  This time lapse may account for the extra 2%.  My guess is the actual increase was 60% in this case.

Comment: Happiness normally increases to 100% after mating. If it was less than 100%, I would suspect another factor, like a disaster in the room before you looked at him.

Comment: I suspect incorrectly.  My little dude walked to the elevator, went down two flights, entered the Med room, and I checked him immediately, possibly 6-7 seconds after mating.

Comment: You suspect incorrectly.  My little dude walked to the elevator, went down two flights, entered the Med room, and I checked him immediately, possibly 10 seconds after mating.  And when I looked at his happiness level at 72, it raised to 73, 74, 75... in roughly 6 seconds.  So it was going up, not down.

Comment: Well that's super odd, then. Without more information I would chalk that up to a bug. Mating raises happiness to 100%.

Comment: @Dervacumen Happiness does not shoot up immediately. It will slowly rise to match whatever level the previous activity dictates. So, after mating, a dweller's happiness will slowly rise (as you saw) until it reaches 100, if not immediately affected by other situations (sickness, proximity to dead bodies, etc.)