# Will my explorer's happiness level affect his quest?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I accidentally sent my Explorer on a quest when his happiness level was 10%. 
Now even after 22 hours he is still at the same level. 
My doubt is whether I have spoiled his otherwise successful quest. 
Pls clarify! [image: old Longfellow's stats]

Comment: 50 is the maximum level. Aside from that, I have no idea if happiness has any effect on success in exploration.

Comment: I have no reason to think that the happiness has any effect. I certainly haven't noticed any difference, but I haven't scienced it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually did explore this recently, and short answer is no. Dweller happiness only affects your "Weekly reports". It has no effect on production, a dwellers SPECIAL, or wasteland expeditions. (This was part of my experiments to find [what *increases* dweller happiness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/267366/73976)).

I tested this by choosing one of my most successful explorers,  and placing him in a room full of corpses (his happiness plummeted from 100 to about 15 in a minute flat) then stuck him out in the wasteland. He was out there for his usual time (~1 day) and still came back with some good loot - it was actually the first time anyone returned with any Legendary items (got a Legendary recipe).

Needless to say I pampered that poor SOB as soon as he stepped inside the Vault.