# How to Repopulate my Vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I lost all of my people except for 3 girls. How can I get more people? I had 38 before they died. I have a Radio station but I know that takes a very long time.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't wish to start over (spent too much on the current vault, or whatever reason), you can do several things:

1. **The radio room:** Yes, it will take a while, but basically, it's your best bet. At this stage, look at how long it'll take to call a new dweller, and quit out of the game, and reload the game when that timer runs out. This will avoid any extra havoc caused by Raiders or Radroach attacks. There is also a chance that a dweller will just randomly appear, and I *believe* the number of dwellers can affect this (less dwellers = higher chance of random dwellers arriving).
2. **Quests:** this is risky, because it leaves your vault under-manned. Occasionally, quests will give you the opportunity to get extra dwellers.

### Some things to remember:

- **All you need is one Male Dweller.** once you have one male dweller *at least*, you can effectively double your population. From there, it becomes a delicate game of balancing who's related to who, but you should be able to get a few more generations out of that.
- **Don't remove dead Dwellers.** You can revive dead dwellers! At a price of course. Yes, leaving corpses lying around can heavily affect your vault happiness, but if it means the difference between an unhappy vault, and a heavily under-manned one, I'd suggest dealing with a few unhappy dwellers for the time being. You can always [raise their happiness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267366/raising-a-dwellers-happiness) later!

Comment: I think #1 is the best option if you don't want to start over. Put 2 people in the radio room (the two with the highest Charisma skill) and see when the next timer runs out, log off until then, and just keep trying until you get a male. Then have them do the deed with the three females, and make sure you have one working for food, water, and power (and you'll likely need to alternate between those three with only 1 dweller working if the other 2 are in the radio room.)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly at this point your best bet is to start over, here is why:

1: You wont be able to sustain your current dwellers and attract new dwellers at the same time.

- You need at least 3 dwellers to gather the 3 main resources just to keep your few dwellers alive (water, power, food). This won't leave anyone to run the radio station to attract new dwellers.

2: You wont be able to defend yourself from disasters, rad-roaches, and raider attacks:

- The intensity and difficulty of disasters and attacks increase as your vault levels up (number of rooms, upgraded rooms, dwellers population, dweller level, etc), dropping from 38 dwellers to 3 wont decrease the difficulty of these attacks, and you wont be able to keep your dwindling population alive for much longer.

3: A better start:

- With the knowledge and experience of a failed vault you're much more likely to succeed with a new vault, especially since you now know what to avoid and what lead to your previously failed vault.

Comment: The attacks are much less frequent with only a couple dwellers. Just like deathclaws only attack after you reach 60 population (I think it's 60) you don't get raider attacks with just 1 or 2 dwellers. (Edit: That's at the beginning of the game.. not sure if that's still the case if most of your population dies.)

Answer (score 0):

You could revive any dead dwellers. They also will appear in your vault over time.

Comment: They were removed because my people would not work