# Why did my dwellers become unhappy when I left the game unattended for an hour?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I left my computer on to go out for ice cream. And I came back and 4 of my dwellers where very unhappy. They are at the bottom of my vault so it couldn't have been a deathclaw. And one of them died so I don't see how one could die of a molerat or a bug because I have 77 people in my vault. Please help me

Comment: What is the issue? You had people die because you left the game running. Are you asking how they died?

Answer (score 3):

[Death is the biggest deficit to happiness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/297577/73976). As for what caused the death, it could be any number of things - especially over an hour's timeframe - multiple attacks and fires would certainly be enough to kill at least one dweller.

Additionally, as [Nelson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334721/73976) has already stated, if you don't have a Mr. Handy on the floor where you generate your food and water (you might have others in the vault - but they won't collect resources on other floors) then your resources won't be collected, and Starvation, dehydration, and loss of power can affect happiness as well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any Mr. Handy?

If you don't, the resources do not collect and your vault will run down.